# How to customize the jsGrid new row position

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

How to customize the position of **new row** in jsGrid. When click on the "+" icon To appear the new row at the end of the table.

**New row in jsGrid:**

[image: new row in jsGrid]

```
_createInsertRow: function() {
        if($.isFunction(this.insertRowRenderer))
            return $(this.renderTemplate(this.insertRowRenderer, this));

        var $result = $("<tr>").addClass(this.insertRowClass);

        this._eachField(function(field) {
            this._prepareCell("<td>", field, "insertcss")
                .append(this.renderTemplate(field.insertTemplate, field))
                .appendTo($result);
        });

        return $result;
    },
```

Comment: Anything I can edit with the above code snippet?

Comment: Have you found the way? Or is the code above for customising it?